# sudo apt-get install npm error

Tags: 14.04, apt, nodejs, npm

When I was about to install nodejs I successfully ran these two commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

However, when I ran `sudo-apt-get install npm` it gave me this list of errors:

```
$ sudo apt-get install npm
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 npm : Depends: nodejs but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-abbrev (>= 1.0.4) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-ansi but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-archy but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-block-stream but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-fstream (>= 0.1.22) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-fstream-ignore but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-github-url-from-git but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-glob (>= 3.1.21) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-graceful-fs (>= 2.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-inherits but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-ini (>= 1.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-lockfile but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-lru-cache (>= 2.3.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-minimatch (>= 0.2.11) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-mkdirp (>= 0.3.3) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-gyp (>= 0.10.9) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-nopt (>= 2.1.1) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-npmlog but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-once but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-osenv but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-read but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-read-package-json (>= 1.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-request (>= 2.25.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-retry but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-rimraf (>= 2.2.2) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-semver (>= 2.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-sha but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-slide but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-tar (>= 0.1.18) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-which but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried these:
http://www.scriptscoop.net/t/853c92c3dcf6/node-js-cannot-be-installed-in-ubuntu.html

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-an-ubuntu-14-04-server

EDIT:

this is not a proper way to install Node.js anyway, instead NVM (Node version manager) should be used. See here: https://github.com/creationix/nvm

Comment: What's the output of `sudo apt-get upgrade`, `sudo apt-get -f install`, and `sudo apt-get --dry-run dist-upgrade`?

Comment: from `sudo apt-get upgrade` last line of output is `0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.`,  from `sudo apt-get -f  install` i get `0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.` and from `sudo apt-get --dry-run dist-upgrade` i get `0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded. ` When I was running similar commands before it also told me I had broken packages, however I fixed that already. When I call install npm the error is still same as before. (the one logged in question)

Comment: Have you added the repository that contains npm?  I know there is a certain one from the developers that's supposed to be better.

Comment: Can you provide more information about that and how to do it (I am ubuntu total beginner (~3days of usage))

Comment: +1 Daniels suggestions, except dist-upgrade (clean install preferred). All the 0 responses don't look right. Have non-standard repos? Normally required dependent packages are installed automatically, if they're available.

Comment: `dist-upgrade` doesn't upgrade the distro.

Comment: Googleing for `how to install npm Ubuntu 14.04` should help. @Kunok

Comment: @Xen2050 Here is for example full log of `sudo apt-get upgrade` => `$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  liblouis-data liblouis2 python3-brlapi python3-louis python3-pyatspi
  python3-speechd
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
`

Comment: @Daniel I already did as I linked guide in question, however they do not mention anything related to my problem.

Comment: I updated question code to show full log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check with following code :

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties python g++ make
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs
npm install
```

to check version,

```
npm -v
```

output will be like this

```
1.4.28
```

Comment: Output is not the same, however very similar. `kunok@Kunok:~$ npm install
npm WARN ENOENT ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/kunok/package.json'
npm WARN EPACKAGEJSON kunok No description
npm WARN EPACKAGEJSON kunok No repository field.
npm WARN EPACKAGEJSON kunok No README data
npm WARN EPACKAGEJSON kunok No license field.
kunok@Kunok:~$ npm -v
3.3.12`

Answer (score 1):

Try to use a method from [here](https://howto.karolak-k.com/install-newest-nodejs-debian-raspberrypi/)

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_7.x | sudo -E bash --
```

and then:

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

Answer (score 1):

After running command

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
```

then

```
sudo aptitude install npm
```

solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

Having run into my fair share of nodejs install issues and then trying to manage versions / npm etc., I came across this repo which has worked wonders for me.

https://github.com/brock/node-reinstall