# Broken npm, so tried aptitude, which broke apt AND aptitude leaving me with no package manager

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, aptitude

So, during a minor update earlier, I noticed that npm wasn't working, so I began updating packages.  I landed on [this similar issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/710019/sudo-apt-get-install-npm-error), so went on to get `aptitude` installed.  Somehow, that installation failed as well.  Everything I tried resulted in pages of this error:

```
E: The method driver /usr/lib/apt/methods/http could not be found.
```

So after a bunch of more messing around, i had `aptitude` uninstall itself, which it did.  But this left me with no `aptitude` OR `apt`.

I tried to download a [few of these](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apt/) and install them with `dpkg` but it fails due to just an endless list of missing dependencies.

```
# dpkg -i apt_1.7.0_i386.deb 
(Reading database ... 151349 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack apt_1.7.0_i386.deb ...
Unpacking apt:i386 (1.7.0) over (1.7.0) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of apt:i386: 
 apt:i386 depends on libapt-pkg5.0 (>= 1.7.0~alpha3~).
 apt:i386 depends on libc6 (>= 2.15).
 apt:i386 depends on libgcc1 (>= 1:4.2).
 apt:i386 depends on libgnutls30 (>= 3.5.6).
 apt:i386 depends on libseccomp2 (>= 1.0.1).
 apt:i386 depends on libstdc++6 (>= 5.2).

dpkg: error processing package apt:i386 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 apt:i386
```

I tried `snap`, but it had a [x509](https://bugs.launchpad.net/snappy/+bug/1620755) error, so I kind of gave up on that as well.

Can someone help me de-muck this stuff up?  All the google searching I've done so far can't tell that I'm trying to re-install `apt-get`, and thinks I want to use `apt-get` to install stuff.

Ubuntu 18.04.1LTS, by the way.  On a live server, 300 miles away.

EDIT: So, this server has mostly been restored to it's initial state and I got npm/nvm/pm2 working again.  Checking the new logs (and old logs) I see that the root of all these issues was a failure of the certificate authority.  Somewhere, in some process, something didn't download over https, and in troubleshooting the failed installation, I likely caused the rest of this mess.

Comment: I am running ubuntu 18.04.1 and my apt version is 1.6.6 could you try that specific version? http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apt/apt_1.6.6_amd64.deb

Comment: Looks like you are (unwisely) trying to mix packages from different releases of Ubuntu, and/or packages from non-Ubuntu sources. Example: libapt-pkg5.0 version 1.7.0~alpha3~ is not a standard Ubuntu version number, and is too high even for 18.10! Looks like you are trying to install 32-bit packages, too (why?) I think you should take this question to our sibling site Ubuntuforums.org, where gurus can hold your hand and patiently work with you one-on-one for the many days (or weeks) it will take to untangle whatever horrors you have done. AskUbuntu's format is not intended for that.

Comment: Yeah, probably.  I think I asked AskUbuntu as that's where most of today's googling landed me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not OP, but I worked on the machine in question just now and figured it's best to put the solution here in case anyone else has the same problem in the future.

I first got a copy of the apt package he removed (1.6.3 instead of 1.7).  This gave me a missing dependency of libgcc1.4.9, which I went and fetched.  libgcc complained about not having gcc-4.9-base, which I then went and found.  gcc-4.9-base installed without issue.  libgcc had a conflict in /usr/local/doc/libgcc1 , so I removed what was already there and reinstalled the dependency.  Then apt installed without issue.  I was able to "apt list" without issue, and handed the machine back to mainstreetmark.